# Add device driver to Windows CE 6.0 through Platform Builder

Tags: windows, embedded, windows-ce, platform-builder

I'm trying to add a device driver to a Windows CE 6.0 image that I'm creating through Platform Builder.

The driver in question, for the VIA 6656 chipset (used in many USB Wi-Fi adapters/dongles), is available in the manufacturer's website and consists of several files: .PDB, .REG, .BIB, .DLL, .MAP and .REL.

I understand that the REG file must be imported in my OSDesign.reg, the BIB file to my OSDesign.bib and the DLL must be placed in the /Windows folder of my image. What I don't understand is what to do with the remaining files (PDB, MAP and REL).

Could anyone assist me in this matter?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For inclusion into the OS, you need only the REG, BIB and DLL.  The remaining files contain debugging symbols, linker information and the like, presumably in case you have an error and want to debug it.  It's odd that you get these, but no source code.  sStill, for including in your OS for use, they're not relevant.

Comment: Thank you, I could make the driver work by adding only the files you mentioned.